# Extracting specific data from a string and summing it according to values contained elsewhere in string

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Performing a subtotal on filtered data from a streamreader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627720/performing-a-subtotal-on-filtered-data-from-a-streamreader)

Data Set: Hundreds of lines of data in "file.dat", each ranging from 80-500 ASCII characters in length.

Located in each string, at specific locations (fixed width not delimited), are 4 relevant pieces of information.

1) -NUMBERS- Always located in the first 3 characters of each string, is a number that states whether the string is relevant to me or not. If it contains any of 210,310 or 410 then I want to process this line, otherwise I want to ignore it.

2) -LETTERS- This information's location is dependent on whether the first 3 digits were 210, 310 or 410. If it is 210, then I want the algorithm to look at the values (always letters), contained in location 406-409. If the first 3 digits were 310, then I need the values from 322-325, and if 410, then what I need is in 478-481.

3 & 4) -NUMBERS- The final 2 pieces of information are numbers, one of which will always be 0, the other will be > 0. Given that I cannot tell which is going to be the nonzero, I wish to add them together. These numbers are in the following locations:

```
       FIRST NUMBER LOCATION  SECOND NUMBER LOCATION             

210: ......... 129-140 ......................................142-153 

310: ..........113-124 ......................................126-137

410: ..........113-124  ......................................126-137
```

What I need to do with this is provide subtotals for each combination of letters in 2). The range of values for 2) is only about 4-5 different arrangements of letters (ABCD, AAAA,BBBB,CCCC,DDDD), so my final output would be:

```
210 AAAA "Total number"

210 BBBB "Total number"

.

.

.

410 DDDD "Total number"

410 ABCD "Total number"
```

etc. for all combinations of the numbers and letters (15 maximum).

I hope this is clear,
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: CURRENT CODE:

i'm currently trying to go about it with a series of if's and lots of var's, hope this code pastes:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Read in a file line-by-line, and store in a List.
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file.dat"))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var beginning = line.Substring(0, 3);
                // building this up atm
                // var letters210 = line.Substring(129,11);
                if (beginning != "210" && beginning != "310" && beginning != "410")
                    continue;

                list.Add(line); // Add to list.
                Console.WriteLine(line); // Write to console.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a daatabase?

Comment: Desperately trying to get a solution for this. My previous question had an upvoted answer (prior to its edit) so was seen as answered, as I'd simplified the situation down too much.

edit- not using a database as I don't have the software :( It would be a simpler solution.

Comment: What code do you have at the moment?

Comment: You have C# and not SQL Server CE?

Comment: Try starting with `if !line.StartsWith("210") && ` etc.

Comment: thanks zev, giving that a try, this gave me a lightbulb moment that I can do most of the above inside that if, trying to figure out the if then else sequence it'll need.  self taught at coding so completely unaware of many of the commands. SQL is a step beyond me at this stage. I can only use access, which I don't have.

Comment: I suggest you stick with `if`, `Substring`, and an `int` variable to hold the total for now. There are much more sophisticated ways of doing this ([implement IEnumerable on StreamReader and use LINQ](http://blog.einbu.no/2009/03/parsing-textfiles-with-linq/), for example) but I suggest you continue as you've begun.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a class whose job is handling a particular type of line and aggregating all the sums:

```
public class LineHandler
{
    // Start indices and lengths for string and two numbers
    int si, sl, n1i, n1l, n2i, n2l;
    Dictionary<string, int> sums;

    public LineHandler(int si, int sl, int n1i, int n1l, int n2i, int n2l)
    {
        this.si = si; this.sl = sl; this.n1i = n1i;
        this.n1l = n1l; this.n2i = n2i; this.n2l = n2l;
        sums = new Dictionary<string,int>();
    }

    public void HandleString(string s)
    {
        string key = s.Substring(si, sl);
        int sum = int.Parse(s.Substring(n1i, n1l)) + int.Parse(s.Substring(n2i, n2l));
        if (sums.ContainsKey(key))
            sums[key] += sum;
        else
            sums[key] = sum;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, int> Sums { get { return sums; } }
}
```

Then you can create a dictionary of these to help select the right one for each line (double-check I've got the lengths right):

```
    Dictionary<string, LineHandler> handlers = new Dictionary<string, LineHandler> {
        { "210", new LineHandler(406, 3, 129, 11, 142, 11) },
        { "310", new LineHandler(322, 3, 113, 11, 126, 11) },
        { "410", new LineHandler(478, 3, 113, 11, 126, 11) } };
    public Dictionary<string, int> Sums { get { return sums; } }
}
```

Then you can just loop over your lines and "handle" each line if there's a handler for it:

```
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string key = line.Substring(0, 3);
    if (handlers.ContainsKey(key))
        handlers[key].HandleString(line);
}
```

Then you can access the values:

```
foreach(string key in handlers.Keys)
{
    LineHandler handler = handlers[key];
    foreach (string s in handler.Sums.Keys)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", key, s, handler.Sums[s]);
}
```

Comment: much appreciated Rawling, will have a look over this and a google to try and understand the Linehandler. Would upvote if i could. Maybe one day when I get that high. :)